# Cut and transpose in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-math

When using cut and pasting LibreOffice maintains exact formula used along with moving old references to point to the new location, however when using paste special: transpose it treats the past as if copy was used (recalculating references relative to new positions and breaking references to the moved cells)

Is there some way to prevent this change of behaviour when transposing or is there another way to transpose these cells whilst maintaining their exact references (as is) and the references to these cells.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> simply toggles the "absoluteness" of every reference within the cells, as some references within the range are absolute it cannot be used to make every reference within them exact.

Aside from manually moving each and every cell is there a method to do this? Even partial solutions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal [transpose](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Rotating_Tables_Transposing) method ([see also](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/29191/how-do-i-convert-rows-into-columns-or-vice-versa-in-calc/) ) or you can use transpose function in Calc. So you must select any cell that must transposed matrix be replaced there, then click on formulas section and choose transpose from list. after choosing main matrix, transposed matrix would be appeared.